# sudo apt -get update error

Tags: unix, sudo, apt

Using `$ sudo apt -get update` shows an error:
Unable to locate an executable at "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_31.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/apt" (-1)

My guess is that the path to the executable should be "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_31.jdk/Contents/Home/bin" (without "/apt")? How can I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try asking this question on http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You would get more traction for your question at https://askubuntu.com/ which is part of StackExchange

Comment: I had this problem before I forgot how I solved it, try to reinstall jdk if you're using openjdk